# How to Start process with Powershell [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start with more the one parameter

Tags: powershell, process, process.start

When I start a process in PS:

This works fine.

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("myprog.exe", "$param1 $param2 /run /SilentMode")
```

But if `$param2` has a space in it will be truncated at the first word. Myprog.exe will insert the 2 strings passed as a parameter in a SQL table.

So this works fine:

```
$param1 = "param1string"
$param2 = "param2string"
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("myprog.exe", "$param1 $param2 /run /SilentMode")
```

But here not. I will have on the table only the first word of the second parameter.

```
$param1 = "param1string"
$param2 = "param2 string string"
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("myprog.exe", "$param1 $param2 /run /SilentMode")
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to double quote a parameter is:

```
$param1 = "param1string" 
$param2 = "`"param2 string string`""
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("myprog.exe", "$param1 $param2 /run /SilentMode")
```

It works for me!

Answer (score -1):

Use start-process https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6

look the examples

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:comspec" -ArgumentList "/c dir `"%systemdrive%\program files`""
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:comspec" -ArgumentList "/c","dir","`"%systemdrive%\program files`""
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem: "Specifies parameters or parameter values to use when this cmdlet starts the process. If parameters or parameter values contain a space, they need to be surrounded with escaped double quotes." But I'm having the problem on finding the way to double quote the $param2.
Someone said: The escape character in Powershell is the "`" (backward apostrophe/grave). How to use it, in my case?